# How to find the url which comes before the first backbone.js token in the given text. I tried all possibilities but not able to do so

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find the url which comes before the first backbone.js token in the given text. I tried all possibilities but not able to do so.

Ref: https://regex101.com/r/rJ1oA8/4

Text: dfjSKsfkfkSFKfdvsfdvsdv https://text.com from https://test2.com sdjgdsdh https://backbone.js from jfsjfskf https://backbone.js jsvdywfiwqkbfs sfgsaifiwf sfasfk https://fggfgf.com

Expected output: https://test2.com

Text can have any number of urls

Comment: What is the expected output? `https://test2.com`?

Comment: as a example I given this, yes it should be backbone.js

Comment: yes, expected output is https://test2.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest this regex:

```
\bhttps?:\/\/\S*(?=(?:(?!http)[\s\S])*https?:\/\/\S*backbone\.com)
```

The `(?:(?!http)[\s\S])*` is a tempered greedy token that ensures the smallest possible window between a URL and another URL with `backbone.com`.

In JS, to match *any* character, even a newline, you need to use `[\s\S]` character class, or a JS-specific `[^]`. For portabililty reasons, I prefer `[\s\S]`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJ1oA8/8)

For a better URL regex, you can see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) or see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203265/3832970) with  [Diego Perini's URL regex](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294).

Comment: But it is not working if the text contains new line charterers inbetween, ref: https://regex101.com/r/rJ1oA8/7

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this

```
https?\:\/\/(?!backbone)\S+\.com(?=(?:(?!http)[^])*https?\:\/\/backbone.js)
```

Demo here(https://regex101.com/r/xP3rR5/1)